# How do i sort a text file by column numerically?

Tags: python-3.x, sorting, text

```
from lxml import html
import operator
import discord
import yaml
import csv



raw_json = 
requests.get('https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getmarketsummaries').text
json_dict = json.loads(raw_json)
stuff = json_dict["result"]
new = []
for i in range(0,197):
    price = (stuff[i]['Last'])
    name1 = (stuff[i]['MarketName'])
    name = name1.replace("BTC-", "")
    prev = (stuff[i]['PrevDay'])
    diff = price - prev
    change = round(((price - prev) / price) * 100, 2)
    final = ('{0},{1}'.format(name,change))
    new.append(final)
butFirst = new[0:]
this1 = ("\n".join(butFirst))
text_file = open("Sort.txt", "w")
text_file.write(this1)
text_file.close()
```

Im having problems sorting this output in second column..
I get base 10 errors.. integer errors etc.. i think the problem
is how the number is stored but i cant figure it out.
output looks like this>

```
1ST,-5.94
2GIVE,3.45
ABY,2.44
ADA,0.0
ADT,-4.87
ADX,-13.09
AEON,-2.86
AGRS,-2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid changing your data to text earlier than you need to. If you operate with a list of dictionaries it's very easy to sort the list.

```
import json
import csv
import requests


raw_json = requests.get('https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getmarketsummaries').text
json_dict = json.loads(raw_json)
stuff = json_dict["result"]
new = []
for i in range(0,197):
    price = float(stuff[i]['Last'])
    prev = float(stuff[i]['PrevDay'])
    # Use dictionary to hold the data
    d = { 
            'name' : stuff[i]['MarketName'].replace("BTC-", ""),
            'change' : round(((price - prev) / price) * 100, 2)
            }
    new.append(d)

# The actual sorting part, sorting by change
sorted_list = sorted(new, key=lambda k: k['change'])

# Writing the dictionaries to file
with open("Sort.txt", "w") as text_file:
    dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(text_file, sorted_list[0].keys())
    # include the line below, if you want headers
    # dict_writer.writeheader()
    dict_writer.writerows(sorted_list)
```